# iOS 11.3 ARKit Autofocus and higher resolution

Tags: ios, arkit

As mentioned [here](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/01/apple-previews-ios-11-3/) Apple is allowing us to use higher resolution and Autofocus in the apps based on ArKit, have anybody already tried implementing those features in own apps ?
Where apple is usually sharing more technical details about such updates ?

Regards !

Answer (score 2):

You haven’t been able to set the ARCamera image resolution... which is why you may not find anything relating to adjusting the camera image resolution. [Changing ARCamera Resolution](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81301)

If you want to check the ARCamera image resolution you can do so access via the currentFrame.

```
let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame
print(currentFrame?.camera.imageResolution)
```

to date it was set to 1280.0, 720.0

if you want more information about focal-length, which i believe auto-focus may now be able to adjust automatically. You can just check the camera property of currentFrame.

```
print(currentFrame?.camera)
```

Comment: Now it's 1920x1080 by default on my iPhone 6s

Comment: I’m doing all my ARKit app development on a 12.9 inch ipad pro... so the low camera resolution has always been a drawback. So I will check later to see the improvment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, autofocus can be added with:
var isAutoFocusEnabled: Bool { get set }

```
var configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true // or false
```

Any clues what about higher res ?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to select desired resolution for AR camera using following code -

```
ARWorldTrackingConfiguration* configuration = [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration new];

NSArray<ARVideoFormat*>* supportedVideoFormats = [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration supportedVideoFormats];

int bestFormatIndex = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [supportedVideoFormats count]; i++) {
    float width = supportedVideoFormats[i].imageResolution.width;
    float height = supportedVideoFormats[i].imageResolution.height;
    NSLog(@"AR Video Format %f x %f", width, height);
    if (width * 9 == height * 16) { // <-- Use your own condition for selecting video format
        bestFormatIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}

[configuration setVideoFormat:supportedVideoFormats[bestFormatIndex]];

// Run the view's session
[_mSceneView.session runWithConfiguration:configuration];
```

For my requirement I wanted biggest 16:9 ratio. On iPhone 8+, following image resolutions are getting listed -

```
1920 x 1440
1920 x 1080
1280 x 720
```

Notice that they are sorted in the supportedVideoFormats array, with biggest resolution at 0 index. And 0th index is the default selected video format.